# Is it ok that i use socket.io to get/ insert mysql data at React-native?

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, socket.io

I m making some randomChatting application with React Native.

So I use Socket.io to implement chatting system.

And I need to add some friend system to my App, So I decide to use MYSQL to save freind datas.

If I use socket to insert or select datas with MYSQL, is it OK?

ex)

Client.js

```
socket.on('getFriendDatas', (datas)=>{
 // use Data to show
})
```

Server.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
//I select Datas from mysql, then 
socket.emit('getFriendDatas', datafromMYSQL);
}
```

like this.

I wonder that use some several sockets in One Application can occur some problems( like.. some malfunction with Server or make some errors with client else..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine.

To handle the data on the app, you'll need to use Redux or something.

But from the backend, you can store that data in any database you'd like. However, Mongo (or other NoSQL) databases are more common with Node than relational databases like MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for answer, But I don't know the exact reason to use Redux. I found some datas and examples with Redux, But I can't find the reason to use it... Can you show me the short usage examples at my Application? I m making randommatching Chatting app :)

Comment: Redux, or other state management libraries, help you keep a global state away from component state. So it can be reused, bring logic to your app, and other cool stuff. As your app grows, you’ll need something to take care of your state. You’ll find component state to be fairly limiting.

Comment: I see.. can I think redux as Singleton at android?

Comment: Yes, you may. Redux will store your entire app state. And then you’ll use actions to modify that state and reducers to structure it. And your components will connect to Redux and consume the state.

Comment: Oh i see .. Thank you for answer!!